# Why isn't my date formatting as expected?

Tags: angularjs

My date from the database table looks like this:

`"2017-12-07 14:42:38.0611177 +00:00"`

I'm trying to format it in my HTML like this:

`<td>{{ note.CreatedAt | date : "MMM d, y" }}</td>`

I was expecting the date to look like this:

`Dec 7, 2017`

But, the result looks like this:
[image: date is not in expected format]

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: (for "2017" you might need `yyyy`) Try to do: `$scope.note.CreatedAt = (new Date($scope.note.CreatedAt)).valueOf();` to use the numeric value: `1512657758061`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey single `y` will display full year :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your date as a timestamp before filter it.

Aleksey remark is a good point, you can get timestamp from controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('dateCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  var date = "2017-12-07 14:42:38.0611177 +00:00";
  $scope.createdAt = new Date(date).valueOf();
}]);
```

And use it in your view:

```
<span>{{createdAt |  date : "MMM d, y"}}</span>
```

Top example will output: `Dec 7, 2017`

**[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SmPbIR8XHEDdZ6KYeWF3)**

For more informations, refer to AngularJS documentation concerning [date filter].[2](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help.